# How to code a script to create a makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

i'm new year and I need some answer. I searched on the web to some answer but i didn't found anything usefull. What am i searching is for a shell programms that when you execute it, create a Makefile with the binary name in arguments like :

./automakefile.sh hello .

Will build you a Makefile with a binary name called hello.

I hope you guys will help me, i'm counting on you <3

Comment: There is no such magic. You may be thinking of [`automake`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/), but it is not that magic.

Comment: "Create a Makefile" is not that simple, a Makefile has some information you have to provide to your script whether in the code or as parameters, such as what are the sources or the target's dependencies, what is the compiler, its arguments, the linker, etc. It's up to you to write such a script or to use some existing tools (CMake, automake, etc.) but they will want some information as well about the Makefile content.

Comment: If it is that simple, then you can use a generic Makefile using an environment variable for the source and binary name.

Answer (score 0):

There is, unfortunately, no such magic command.  If there was, we wouldn't need Makefiles to start with because the magic would most likely have been incorporated in the compiler.

There are several reasons why there isn't a command like that.

1. Given a random binary file, you can't generally say what programming language it was written in.
2. You also can't tell what source file were used to compile the binary file from, or where in the file hierarchy they *are* located (not just where they *were* located when the binary file was compiled last time, maybe on another system).
3. You don't know the dependencies between the source code files. Makefiles are primarily useful for keeping track of these (and compiler flags etc.), so that changing one single source file in a big project does not trigger a recompilation of everything.
4. You don't know what compiler to use, or what flags to pass to it. This is another thing a Makefile contains.

There are build tools available for making the creation of Makefiles easier, and for making them portable between systems on different architectures (the Makefiles that is, not necessarily the programs, that's down to the programmer). One such set of tool is [GNU's autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html), another is [CMake](https://cmake.org/), and I'm sure there are others as well, but those are the ones I use.

Now you're facing *another* but similar problem, and that is that you *still need to learn the syntax of, and writ,e* your `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac` files (for the GNU tools), or your `CMakeLists.txt` files (for CMake).